# How to access rows and columns by name from an R matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Given a `matrix` object:

```
Browse[2]> class(coldists)
[1] "matrix"
```

That has named rows and columns:

```
Browse[2]> coldists
            pregnant    glucose     diastolic   skin        insulin     bmi         pedigree    age        
estimate    Numeric,2   Numeric,2   Numeric,2   Numeric,2   Numeric,2   Numeric,2   Numeric,2   Numeric,2  
method      "mle"       "mle"       "mle"       "mle"       "mle"       "mle"       "mle"       "mle"      
sd          Numeric,2   Numeric,2   Numeric,2   Numeric,2   Numeric,2   Numeric,2   Numeric,2   Numeric,2  
cor         Numeric,4   Numeric,4   Numeric,4   Numeric,4   Numeric,4   Numeric,4   Numeric,4   Numeric,4  
vcov        Numeric,4   Numeric,4   Numeric,4   Numeric,4   Numeric,4   Numeric,4   Numeric,4   Numeric,4  
loglik      -2022.201   -3750.272   -3364.823   -3216.296   -4734.98    -2675.054   -240.8774   -2982.152  
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 11 rows ]
```

How can those columns/rows be accessed by name?

```
Browse[2]> coldists$estimate
NULL
```

There is a general question here: why is it difficult to find the attributes of a matrix/dataframe etc?   From either `RStudio` editor or terminal the `tab` or spacebar do not come up with any suggestions after entering the `colname` variable name. There is likely a general approach to getting help/variable details here that I am missing.  E.g. how can those `rownames` such as `estimate`, `method`, etc be accessed?

Comment: `mat[<rownames>, <colnames>]` to access elements, e.g. `coldists["estimate", "diastolic"]`. `dimnames(coldists)` to see the names.

Comment: Tab completion should work for the column names of a data frame (but not matrix).

Comment: @Marius thx but all of the examples you showed are `NULL`

Comment: @neilfws I converted to df: `coldists = as.data.frame(coldists)` : that seems promising but fyi tab completion still does not work. at least now the lookup `coldists["pregnant"] does work.  I'd like to find out how to nab the first row "estimate" - probably a filter operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the comments, but with a working example:

```
m <- matrix(1:6, 2)
rownames(m) <- c("A", "B")

m["B", ]
# [1] 2 4 6
```

Comment: ouch I see.  The matrix *itself* does *not* have these methods. `rownames` is an *independent* method.  This is making learning/discovering how to use the `R` constructs more challenging.

Comment: More correct would be to say that row names are an optional attribute of matrices (see `attr(m, "dimnames")`), `rownames()` is just a shortcut for assigning those attributes. The methods of interest are in the `[` function. You can access the relevant documentation through `?'['`.

Comment: `R` data structures are not straightforward: many gotchas. E.g. `[[` vs `[` , methods that are standalone vs living on the object itself, more..

Comment: example in `?matrix` in R 3.5.3. `mdat <- matrix(c(1,2,3, 11,12,13), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(c("row1", "row2"), c("C.1", "C.2", "C.3")))`. Access the column "C.1" as `mdat[,"C.1"]`